# Timeline Style JQuery Scroller

Tags: jquery, image, timeline, scroller

Hey, not exactly looking for code help as it's too much to ask for someone just to write it up, I assume, but basically I'm in need of a script that will display a single div (that contains text and image) but with a scrollbar bellow it and as you scroll the scrollbar the content changes to the next div.

The idea of it is for a uni project where the scrollbar represents the timeline so as you move the bar along the content in the middle will change to represent the time on the scrollbar.

So, if anybody could help me out or know of a script that does this it would be amazing.

PS. it's 87 divs long.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably get you started if you couple it with the jqueryui slider control:

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/